# Different orientation behavior of modalviewcontroller between iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've become completely lost trying to understand this particular behavior in iOS.  After 14 hours, reading countless Stack Overflow questions, and perusing all the relevant Apple docs, I'm still very confused—so I'm hoping a concrete example will help an expert explain it to me.

I have a modal view controller that I am presenting (this problem behavior applies with any of Apple's premade modalviewcontrollers, doesn't seem to matter which.)

In simplest terms, I have the device rotated to landscape.  If I call:

```
[rootViewController presentModalViewController:modalVC animated:YES];
```

On the iPhone, it is presented as expected.
On the iPad, it is also presented as expected (contained as page with a greyed out background)

Later, in the modalVC's delegate for its built-in 'done' button, I call:

```
[rootViewController dissmissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Here is where the symptoms begin:

On the iPhone, *regardless* of whether the rootViewController's shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation returns YES or NO, the status bar immediately enters a portrait orientation; the modal then slides out in the wrong (portrait, to the right) direction, and the underlying rootViewController is now displayed in portrait, without having its shouldAutoRotate been queried.

On the iPad, I get expected behavior—the modal is dismissed as expected and the orientation remains as expected.

What am I not understanding here?  I've tried many things, including overriding the shouldAUtoRotate behavior of the modalViewController, and using various container viewControllers.  The only effective solution was to create a stub UIViewController, attach its view to the keyWindow, and present the modal within it instead.  While this solves the issue, numerous Apple and offsite articles declare this to be incorrect (with good reason, as it prevents proper event propogation from reaching that stub UIViewController.)

Comment: A minimal project with a root view controller and a modal controller does not exhibit the behaviour you are seeing. I think you will need to post a stripped-down version of your code if you want any help here.

Comment: Can you post the shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation code for your root view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Many apologies here guys.  As usual with these types of things, its developer (me) error.  I'm posting what happened in case someone else gets here.

This is for a static library implemented in a third party application.  (Flash, in this case) for which I do not have the source code.  Some deep debugging revealed what should've been obvious I guess-  the third party application using my library was making some questionable calculations in its own shouldAutoRotate function, and returning NO for -any- toInterfaceOrientation argument in certain conditions (not right.)